# C++ Algorithm to search for specific sequence of integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, sequence

Let's say that I have a specific sequence of integers. It must not be sorted. There is no probability distribution to the frequency of integers:

```
S = [12 65 37 52 45 63].
```

Now let's say I have a group of 100 different sequences, called D, that I must search through. D must not sorted in anyway. There is no probability distribution in D. Each sequence in D has the same length as S.

Is there an algorithm that quickly searches through D for exactly the specific sequence S?

Comment: what is the programming language?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not sorted"? Why is not being sorted in any way a requirement?

Comment: Because the data are from an experiment.

Comment: You can iterate over the array and search the first element, then check if the subsequence is valid starting from there. If it's not, go on with the next element and so on to the end. Is it that big your N that you must further optimize it?

Comment: Yes. There are over 300,000 different sequences of S. Each S has its own group D. D can have >100 sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You should preprocess D. Try to insert all sequences of D into a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

This way you can check if a sequence S of length `n` is in D in time `O(n)`, which is optimal because at least you have to read S once.